# Split strings by multiple separators while including the operator in the result

Tags: regex, r

How do you split character strings like `Start>=8.5` or `Start< 14.5` by the comparison operators - `>=`, `<=`, `>`, `<` - **keeping** the operatiors in the result? The desired output would consist of three elements, e.g.:

```
output[1]
Start 

output[2]
>= 
output[3]
8.5
```

And in the case of the second string:

```
output[1]
Start

output[2]
<

output[3]
14.5
```

I have tried `sapply(x, function(x) strsplit(x, ">=|<", perl = TRUE))`, but this removes the separator.

Comment: Bit of a hack but `strsplit(x = deparse(quote(Start>=8.5)), " ")` works

Comment: [One possibility](https://regex101.com/r/cR4yI4/1)

Comment: What can be before the operators? Do you want to validate those parts somehow?

Comment: Some strings which refer to column names. These are rules from a decision tree...

Comment: I'd go with something like `output <- str_match_all(input, "(.*?)\\s*([<>=]+)\\s*(.*)")` after adding `library(stringr)` if the strings are all in the known format.

Comment: Are you "character"s valid binary operations? Perhaps, you could parse them: `lapply(c("Start>=8.5", "Start< 14.5"), function(x) as.list(parse(text = x)[[1L]])[c(2, 1, 3)])`

Comment: isn't `strsplit(x, '(?=[><=])', perl = TRUE)` all that is needed?

Comment: @rawr: No, `[1] "Start" ">"     "="     "8.5"`

Comment: Be careful, in this case the more complicated the regex solution, the more error prone the results will be. Keep it simple as possible. Get the parts, do the validation later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `strsplit` with the following PCRE regex:

```
strsplit(input, '(?<=[><=])(?=[^><=])|(?<=[^><=])(?=[><=])', perl = TRUE)
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/FAuIqT) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJ5rR7/1).

*Details*:

The regex contains 2 alternatives separated with an OR `|` pipe symbol. The first part - `(?<=[><=])(?=[^><=])` - has 2 zero-width assertions that match the empty location between an operator symbol from the defined character class (`[><=]`) and a symbol other than the one defined in the negated character class (`[^><=]`). The second alternative matches the empty location between a character other than the one belonging to the operator class, and the one that does. Thus, *in fact, we match 2 locations before and after the operators.*

**Alternative solution** based on *stringr* `str_match_all`:

```
> library(stringr)
> input <- c("Start>=8.5","Start< 14.5","x == 4","tmp >= 7","ff =11","x<=2")
> output <- str_match_all(input, "([^=<>]*?)\\s*([<>=]+)\\s*(.*)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJ5rR7/2), the `([^=<>]*?)\\s*([<>=]+)\\s*(.*)` pattern has 3 capture groups that capture the part before the operator (`([^=<>]*?)`), the operator itself (`([<>=]+)`), and then what follows it (`(.*)`).

Comment: why can't you add a quantifier to a look ahead, match <>= as many as possible

Comment: @rawr: You cannot quantify zero-width assertions. Also, in PCRE regex, you cannot use patterns of unknown width in the lookbehind.

Comment: @rawr - it's not relevant. An assertion block can't be quantified. I mean you can put a quantifier there, but it's meaningless since it just repeats the assertion at the same place in the string. For that reason, the engine compiler ignores it. Won't throw an error though. Any variableness has to be moved into the assertion. Inside the assertion the position changes, outside no.

Answer (score 0):

This regex seems to work

```
([^\s<>=]*)\s*(?=[><=]+)(.*)(?<=[><=])\s*(.[^\s<>=]*)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kF1mW0/2)**

*R Code*

```
input <- c("Start>=8.5","Start< 14.5","x == 4","tmp >= 7","ff =11","x<=2")
splitted<-strsplit(gsub("([^\\s<>=]*)\\s*(?=[><=]+)(.*)(?<=[><=])\\s*(.[^\\s<>=]*)", "\\1 \\2 \\3", input, perl=T), " ")
splitted
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/2mUGW6)**

Comment: you need to escape `\\s`..its not for splitting though..its for matching `temp<-c("Start>=8.5")
lapply(temp,function(x){gsub("([^\\s<>=]*)\\s*(?=[><=]+)(.*)(?<=[><=])\\s*(.[^\\s<>=]*)", "\\1 \\2 \\3", x, perl=T)})`

Comment: @DatamineR It will work, but you have to use other libraries present in `R` for finding the match

Comment: @DatamineR [regex crew does not really care if they answer the question in context or not](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14737451/revisions)

Comment: @rawr well we care, but the absence of matching of capturing groups in `R` makes it very painful

Comment: @rawr its bit of hackish, but I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do a global find-all kind of thing to get it into an array.
Do any validation of operator lhs/rhs with the resulting array.

`((?:<=?|>=?)|(?:(?!<=?|>=?).)+)`
*(where the capture group is optional)*

Expanded

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      (?: <=? | >=? )
   |  
      (?:
           (?! <=? | >=? )
           . 
      )+
 )                             # (1 end)
```